# RegularExpressionValidator for multiple emails

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, email

I'm validating a textbox for valid email with this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
ControlToValidate="txtMailCustom"
Text="Invalid address"
ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]
{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" runat="server" />
```

Now I want users to be able to put multiple email addresses , separated by a comma and space.

How can I integrate that behaviour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this expression:

```
^(\s*,?\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})+\s*$
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the expression below, which works for me:

```
((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*
```

The above code is for `,`, separating e-mail addresses.

If you would like to use `;` instead of `,`, than replace `,` with `;` at the end of the above expression.

Comment: if someone type email like this 

abc@abc.comabc@abc.com

How I suppose to validate like this

Answer (score 0):

I should do this: what it does is check for at least one mail, and for list of email before it with each a comma and possibly a space.

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?), ?)*^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Use this if the space between each mail is required:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?), )*^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Note I just used your single mail checker as a base and didn't really edit it.